# Magento 2: Custom Module Color Picker

Tags: magento2

In Magento 1.x I could use the included color picker by using the following form element:

```
$fieldset->addField('title_color', 'text', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('categorybanner')->__('Title Color'),
      'class'  => 'color {hash:true,required:false}',
      'required'  => false,
      'name'      => 'title_color',
  ));
```

Is there an included color picker element in Magento 2? If not how would I go about including a custom JS file on an admin grid?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159254/colorpicker-field-in-admin-form/159313

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out JSColor:

http://jscolor.com/

Its an open source and very easy to use Javascript library. All you have to do is import the library somewhere in your application, than you can simply create an input with the class "jscolor".

Get jscolor.js from above site and add inside  `Vendor/Modulename/view/adminhtml/web/js/jscolor.js`

define js in your module xml head tag or create default.xml file inside  `Vendor/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>      
        <script src="Vendor_Modulename::js/jscolor.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Now set color picker in input like below:

```
$fieldset->addField('title_color', 'text', array(
      'label'     => __('Title Color'),
      'class'  => 'jscolor {hash:true,refine:false}',
      'required'  => false,
      'name'      => 'title_color',
  ));
```

This is working fine in magento 2.

Comment: Is it possible in store configuration page?

Comment: @Dmitry, yes, its possible, ask your question separately, its a good one for all of us

Comment: How to add color picker in admin configuration?

Comment: We can add color picker in Magento 2 admin configuration page as: http://www.webspeaks.in/2016/03/add-color-picker-in-magento-2-admin-configuration-options.html

Answer (score 0):

Follow below step

**Create System.xml at Below Path**

app/code/Emizentech/Newsletter/etc/adminhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">


<system>
    <tab id="emizentechnewsletter" translate="label" sortOrder="700">
        <label>Emizentech Newsletter Pop-up</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="emizentechnewsletter" translate="label" sortOrder="500" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Emizentech Newsletter Configuration</label>
        <tab>emizentechnewsletter</tab>
        <resource>Emizentech_Newsletter::config</resource>


        <group id="txt" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">


            <label>Emizentech</label>


            <field id="colorsample" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="1">
                <label>Font color for newsletter popup</label>
                <comment><![CDATA[Text color]]></comment>
                <frontend_model>Emizentech\Newsletter\Block\Color</frontend_model> <!-- Our block for attaching color picker to text box -->
            </field>
        </group>


    </section>
</system>

</config>
```

**Create Color.php File at below Path**

```
<?php

namespace Emizentech\Newsletter\Block;
class Fontcolor extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param Registry $coreRegistry
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
    $html = $element->getElementHtml();
    $value = $element->getData('value');

    $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
        require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"], function ($) {


            $(document).ready(function () {
                var $el = $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '");
                $el.css("backgroundColor", "'. $value .'");

                // Attach the color picker
                $el.ColorPicker({
                    color: "'. $value .'",
                    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                        $el.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>';
    return $html;
}
}
```

**Add color picker CSS library:**

Create adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml at Below Path

app/code/Emizentech/Newsletter/view/adminhtml/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
</head>
```