# Magento 2.1.1 - How to add color picker in admin configuration options?

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration

How to add color picker in magento 2.1.1 admin system config custom module general settings

[image: color picker error]

Comment: You check this answer ? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103316/magento-2-how-to-add-color-picker-in-admin-configuration-options

Comment: yes i have checked its working only upto magento 2.0.9 its not working in magento 2.1.0  and magento 2.1.1

Comment: Wait i will post the screen for the issue i have faced

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the output,
Need to do two changes,

1)In the Test\Color\Block\Color.php,

Add the path in require.js , 
require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"],

```
    namespace Test\Color\Block;
    class Color extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
    {
        /**
         * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
         * @param array                                   $data
         */
        public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
        ) 
        {
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }
         /**
         @param  \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
         Input  : add color picker in admin configuration fields
         Output : return string script
         */
        protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
        {
            $html = $element->getElementHtml();
            $value = $element->getData('value');

            $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
                require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"], function ($) {
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        var $el = $("#'.$element->getHtmlId().'");
                        $el.css("backgroundColor", "'.$value.'");

                        // Attach the color picker
                        $el.ColorPicker({
                            color: "'.$value.'",
                            onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                                $el.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
                </script>';

            return $html;
        }
    }
```

2) In the app/code/Test/Color/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml.
Please do remove .js file.

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
        </head>
    </page>
```

Comment: This is verified in Magento 2.1.7. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Create system.xml at app/code/Webspeaks/Color/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

All admin config options for your module will go in this file. For color picker we will create a text field as below.
Note: I have not added complete code for sake of readability.

```
<!-- File: app/code/Webspeaks/Color/etc/adminhtml/system.xml -->

<config ...>
    <system>
        ...
        <section>
            ...
            <group id="my_color_group" ...>
                <field id="my_color_option" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Background Color</label>
                    <comment><![CDATA[Background color]]></comment>
                    <frontend_model>Webspeaks\Color\Block\Color</frontend_model> <!-- Our block for attaching color picker to text box -->
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

> 2. Create the Webspeaks\Color\Block\Color.php

This block will enable color picker options with the text box.

```
<?php
#File: app/code/Webspeaks/Color/Block/Color.php

namespace Webspeaks\Color\Block;

class Color extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
        $html = $element->getElementHtml();
        $value = $element->getData('value');

        $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
            require(["jquery"], function ($) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var $el = $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '");
                    $el.css("backgroundColor", "'. $value .'");

                    // Attach the color picker
                    $el.ColorPicker({
                        color: "'. $value .'",
                        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                            $el.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>';
        return $html;
    }

}
```

> 3. Add the color picker JavaScript library

Now finally we need to add color picker JavaScript library to admin config pages. Magento 2 by default is shipped with Color picker jQuery plugin. This plugin is present in lib/web/jquery/colorpicker/ folder.
Create the app/code/Webspeaks/Color/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml. This layout file will be called on all admin configuration pages. We will add our color picker JavaScript and CSS to this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
        <link src="jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

This is the code for it.
And if you want reference then I got it from [HERE](http://www.webspeaks.in/2016/03/add-color-picker-in-magento-2-admin-configuration-options.html).

Comment: It's not working for magento2.1 will work on magento2.0x

Comment: I done it in new magento and its works so I gave you solution.

Comment: On Magento version 2.1?

Comment: Yes in Magento 2.1.1

Comment: Thank you for your answer its not working in Magento 2.1.0 and Magento  2.1.1 its working only upto magento 2.0.9

Comment: Try this 

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91316/magento-2-custom-module-color-picker/156053#156053

Comment: in Magento ver. 2.0.18 i used the above code it works as expected but some time it fails , i mean in console it gives ```(index):421 Uncaught TypeError: $el.ColorPicker is not a function``

Comment: Doesn't work for magento 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Follow below step

**Create system.xml at Below Path**

app/code/Emizentech/Newsletter/etc/adminhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">


<system>
    <tab id="emizentechnewsletter" translate="label" sortOrder="700">
        <label>Emizentech Newsletter Pop-up</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="emizentechnewsletter" translate="label" sortOrder="500" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>separator-top</class>
        <label>Emizentech Newsletter Configuration</label>
        <tab>emizentechnewsletter</tab>
        <resource>Emizentech_Newsletter::config</resource>


        <group id="txt" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">


            <label>Emizentech</label>


            <field id="colorsample" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="1">
                <label>Font color for newsletter popup</label>
                <comment><![CDATA[Text color]]></comment>
                <frontend_model>Emizentech\Newsletter\Block\Color</frontend_model> <!-- Our block for attaching color picker to text box -->
            </field>
        </group>


    </section>
</system>

</config>
```

**Create Color.php File at below Path**

```
<?php

namespace Emizentech\Newsletter\Block;
class Fontcolor extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field {

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param Registry $coreRegistry
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element) {
    $html = $element->getElementHtml();
    $value = $element->getData('value');

    $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
        require(["jquery","jquery/colorpicker/js/colorpicker"], function ($) {


            $(document).ready(function () {
                var $el = $("#' . $element->getHtmlId() . '");
                $el.css("backgroundColor", "'. $value .'");

                // Attach the color picker
                $el.ColorPicker({
                    color: "'. $value .'",
                    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                        $el.css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex).val("#" + hex);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>';
    return $html;
}
}
```

**Add color picker CSS library:**

Create **adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml** at Below Path

app/code/Emizentech/Newsletter/view/adminhtml/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="jquery/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css"/>
</head>
```